How can I approach this integro-differential equation?
In dimension $d=1$ and with domain being $\mathbb{R}$ I consider the following equation I am keen to solve:
\begin{align}
    c \frac{\partial^2 p(x|x_0)}{\partial x^2} - p(x|x_0) + \int_{0}^y dx'\, p(x'|x_0) = 0.
\end{align}
The object here are as follows: $p(x)$ is a probability distribution. $p(x|x_0)$ represents the conditional probability of $x$ given $x_0$. We can interpret it as the physical problem of computing the probability of a continuous random walker being at state $x$ given initial position $x_0$. The last term computes the probability that the walker "finds themselves" with a ball of radius $y$ far from $x=0$. Essentially, we are considering a random walker diffusing freely in $\mathbb{R}$ with the "condition" that if they find themselves $y$-close to the origing we want to disregard this probability (second term) but we still want to know how many times this may happen and thus we integrate over the probability for the walker to be within this ball. I imply a single time step here, this is why there is no explicit time.
Essentially we are keen to compute the stationary distribution for such a walker where once they find themselves $y$-close to the state $x=0$ they jump out and continue as before from this new, randomly sampled, position.
How does one approach such an integral? Are there some Fourier techniques or discretization tricks for this? Are there assumption need to be made, e.g. to consider a bounded domain ${D} \subset \mathbb{R}$ to make life easier?
